# Differential equations math question?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

We have the equation $xy' -4y - x^2 \sqrt{y} =0$
I modify this a little and I have $dx ( 4y-x^2 \sqrt{y}) -xdy=0$
 I am thinking about solving this by integrating factors,but that is quite a long way..is there any short method?

Comment: Markdown tip: You can use two spaces at the and of line to make a [new line](http://math.stackexchange.com/editing-help#linebreaks).

Answer (score 0):

Substitute $u=\frac{y}{x^4}$.

$u'=\frac{x^4y'-4yx^3}{x^8}=\frac{xy'-4y}{x^5}$

$y'=x^4u'+4\frac{y}{x}$

$x^5u'+4y-4y-x^4\sqrt{u}=0$

$u'=\frac{\sqrt{u}}{x}$

$2\sqrt{u}=\ln{x}+C$

$\sqrt{y}=\frac{1}{2}(x^2\ln{x}+Cx^2)$

Comment: You should add the case where $y$ is identically zero.